# I keep receiving the same error with my code "AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'get'"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I keep receiving the same error with my code "AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'get'"

any help?

**code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd


import chromedriver_binary


wd = wd.Chrome()

wd.implicitly_wait(10)


wd.get("http://google.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with naming.
Try this, I hope it will fix your problem

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd


import chromedriver_binary


driver = wd.Chrome()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)


driver.get("http://google.com")
```

With your original names you are attempting to assign `wd.Chrome()` to the `selenium.webdriver` module.
After that you attempting to set `implicitly_wait(10)` on `selenium.webdriver`
And finally you attempting to apply `.get("http://google.com")` on `selenium.webdriver`
That is how Python interprets your code