# Module selenium.webdriver has no attribute "get"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to run a script in Python to make Chrome open up to a specific page. Here is my code so far

[Code part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktNMP.jpg)

[Code part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ffFD.jpg)

The code is

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Then

```
driver = wd.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

Then

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
```

Despite the error message in the screenshot after the second cell, Chrome opens when I run the script. It just opens to a blank page. I've tried changing the name of driver and wd and webdriver and I get the "module selenium.webdriver has no attribute "get"" every time. [This post from yesterday is similar to what I'm having trouble with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68074335/i-keep-receiving-the-same-error-with-my-code-attributeerror-module-selenium-w)
but the solution isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but try one of the following:

1. remove `wd` as it causing misleading

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

2. or this

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = wd.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = wd.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

But please don't mix between them.
I prefer the first option.

Comment: I tried both and still get the same result of a blank page opening and "module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'get'"